# Commutative symbolic functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Suppose I define a function f:

```
f=sympy.Function('f',commutative=True)
```

This function is commutative since I did ask it to be one.

```
f(2),f(x),f("h")
```

Are all commutative. That can be checked by the command `.is_commutative`.

However, if we use a Tuple inside the function f it will not be commutative anymore, even if I ask it to be commutative.

```
f([1,2]).is_commutative==False
```

Is there a way to make the function f commutative while using tuples.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using an older version of SymPy because when I test this it raises an error. When I test this with a tuple -- note that you used a *list*, not a tuple -- it does not fail and maintains the commutativity setting:

```
>>> f((1, 2)).is_commutative
True
```

Comment: I just updated the version of sympy on my computer and it worked. However, usually we don't need to tell the computer that the function is commutative and it will be commutative like `f(2)`, but for tuples and sets I need to tell that the function is commutative. Thanks you very much for your help.